# Mongoose connection to replica set cluster with ssl failed

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have a mongo replica set cluster with a ssl server validation. How can i connect to this with mongoose?

```
 const key = fs.readFileSync(<Path to file>);

 mongoose.connect(dbConectionString, {
    sslCA: key,
    useNewUrlParser: true,
    useUnifiedTopology: true,
    useCreateIndex: true,
 }).then((x) => {
    console.log('connected');
 }).catch((err) => {
    console.log(err);
 });
```

The File has no file ending and looks like this:

```
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
MrPXxLy9NPj8isOutrLD29IY2A0V4RlcIxS0L7sVOy0zD6pmzMMQMD/5ifuIX6bq
[16 more rows]
VF1talRQZJjwryXlXboCG4156MKpL201L2WWjk0rvPUZ
-----END CERTIFICATE-----
```

This works (MongoDB Compass)

[image: MongoDB Compass]

Error Message with this setup

```
   connection error: MongooseError [MongooseServerSelectionError]: connection <monitor> to <server-ip>:<server-port> closed
    at new MongooseServerSelectionError (D:\git_repos\WirVsVirus\Coronahelfer-Hackathon\node_modules\mongoose\lib\error\serverSelection.js:22:11)
    at NativeConnection.Connection.openUri (D:\git_repos\WirVsVirus\Coronahelfer-Hackathon\node_modules\mongoose\lib\connection.js:823:32)
    at Mongoose.connect (D:\git_repos\WirVsVirus\Coronahelfer-Hackathon\node_modules\mongoose\lib\index.js:333:15)
    at new DBConection (D:\git_repos\WirVsVirus\Coronahelfer-Hackathon\.build\src\config\db\connection.js:13:28)
    at Server.dbConfig (D:\git_repos\WirVsVirus\Coronahelfer-Hackathon\.build\src\server.js:31:20)
    at new Server (D:\git_repos\WirVsVirus\Coronahelfer-Hackathon\.build\src\server.js:18:14)
    at Function.bootstrap (D:\git_repos\WirVsVirus\Coronahelfer-Hackathon\.build\src\server.js:24:16)
    at Object.<anonymous> (D:\git_repos\WirVsVirus\Coronahelfer-Hackathon\.build\src\server.js:36:23)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1151:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1171:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1000:32)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:899:14)
    at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (internal/modules/run_main.js:71:12)
    at internal/main/run_main_module.js:17:47 {
  message: 'connection <monitor> to <server-ip>:<server-port> closed',
  name: 'MongooseServerSelectionError',
  reason: TopologyDescription {
    type: 'Single',
    setName: null,
    maxSetVersion: null,
    maxElectionId: null,
    servers: Map(1) {
      '<server-ip>:<server-port>' => [ServerDescription]
    },
    stale: false,
    compatible: true,
    compatibilityError: null,
    logicalSessionTimeoutMinutes: null,
    heartbeatFrequencyMS: 10000,
    localThresholdMS: 15,
    commonWireVersion: null
  },
  [Symbol(mongoErrorContextSymbol)]: {}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Found a solution. add ssl=true to your connection string

```
this.DB_URL = 'mongodb://user:password@ip:port/collection?authSource=admin&ssl=true';
```